# Will an international student owe capital gain taxes upon selling the property if they didn't live there for 4 years?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, rental-property, property-taxes

I am trying to figure out the Capital Gain taxes on a property in Toronto. I am very new to this, so sorry if I say something weird.

I live in a condo, which I own, and I am thinking of renting it.

I have lived here for the past three years, and it is the only property that I own(it was fully transferred to me as a gift), so it is my principle residence at this moment.

From what I understand, If I were to sell this property now, I will not have to pay any capital income taxes, as principle residence is not taxed. [source 1](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/personal-income/line-127-capital-gains/principal-residence-other-real-estate.html)

Also, from what I understand, as soon as I begin renting the condo, it will loose its status as a principle residency, and I will have to pay 1/2 of the price increase in each year that it is a rental property.

However, [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/personal-income/line-127-capital-gains/principal-residence-other-real-estate/changes-use/changing-your-principal-residence-a-rental-business-property.html), I see that it is possible to still keep its status of principle residency for up to 4 years, thus not paying any capital gains for those 4 years, as long as one is *a resident of Canada* and they do not deem their other property as their principal residency.

Now, *I am not a permanent resident or a citizen*, I am a student, on a student visa and a study permit. Will I be able to keep the property's status of principle residence, thus not owing any capital gain taxes upon selling it, if I go back to living in this property in 4 years?

Note: I am likely to receive a permanent resident status during those 4 years through a common law partner sponsorship. Will this somehow affect the taxes?

Also: I will be living in my girlfriend's apartment in those 4 years, and I do not own any parts of it.

Thank you for your help! Sorry for a terribly long post, first time posting on StackExchange.

Comment: Taxes for which country?

Comment: Canada. I guess the real question really is whether what they mean by a resident on their website equals to what is meant by a permanent resident immigration-wise.

Comment: I believe you would be considered a resident for tax purposes. Tax residency is only loosely related to immigration residency. But you can phone CRA and ask them.

Answer (score -1):

Hire an accountant.

Tax rules are personal.

Tax rules regarding large transactions could have tremendous implications if you aren't every single aspect of the rules properly.

Tax on large transctions + DIY = foolishness.

If you don't have the time, that's fine, have your manager hire one.

If you can't afford an accountant or a manager, then it's a bit of a foolish move to buy a condo in the first place, and to consider selling.